# Unable to save output in .txt format

Tags: python, web-scraping

```
for link in data_1:
    a= link.find('a').get("href")

    url_2= a
    response_2 = requests.get(url_2)
    soup_2 = BeautifulSoup(response_2.content, "html.parser")
    #print(soup_2.prettify())
    for i in range(0,5):
        specs_1 = soup_2.find_all(class_="_gry-bg _spctbl _ovfhide")[i].find('table')
        for tr_1 in specs_1.find_all('tr'):
                general = tr_1.find_all('td')[0].text + ":" + tr_1.find_all('td')[1].text
                print(general)
```

Comment: Where in the code are you trying to save output in txt. file?

Comment: just tell me how will i save 'general' output into .txt format

Comment: output shows in this format:
Form factor:Touchscreen
Dimensions (mm):146.70 x 71.50 x 7.40
Weight (g):189.00
IP rating:IP68
Removable battery:No
Fast charging:Proprietary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to save 'general' as a string, then the easiest way would be to just use open() and then write() method upon file object

Something like that:

```
with open("general.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    # Your code here
    file.write(general) # also add '\n' char at the end if you need to
```

I would suggest to check a doc page about Python I/O if you need something more specific:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.write